Strange result from Mercator projection
I want to draw a SIC distribution in Prydz Bay, but I found the result from the Mercator projection to be strange.
I drew both in ccrs.SouthPolarStereo and ccrs.Mercator, the former result is wanted, but I need to draw in Mercator projection, so how can I revise it?
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[10, 5])
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1, projection=ccrs.SouthPolarStereo())
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.05, top=0.95,
                    left=0.04, right=0.95, wspace=0.02)

# Limit the map to -60 degrees latitude and below.
ax1.set_extent([-180, 180, -90, -50], ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax1.add_feature(cfeature.LAND)
cf = ax1.contourf(lon, lat, SIC[0] ,levels=np.linspace(0,1,51),cmap=cmaps.WhiteBlueGreenYellowRed,
                    transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),extend='neither',transform_first=True)
ax1.gridlines()

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2, projection=ccrs.Mercator())
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.05, top=0.95,
                    left=0.04, right=0.95, wspace=0.02)
# Limit the map to -60 degrees latitude and below.


cf = ax2.contourf(lon, lat, SIC[0] ,levels=np.linspace(0,1,51),cmap=cmaps.WhiteBlueGreenYellowRed,
                    transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),extend='neither',transform_first=True)
ax2.add_feature(cfeature.LAND)
ax2.gridlines()

plt.show()




You say you want to draw Prydz Bay, but you seem to be drawing all of Antarctica. You say that you want the result of a polar stereographic projection, but you also want to use Mercator. None of this makes any sense. Could you perhaps include a (hand drawn, if necessary) sketch of what you want the map to look like?

tl;dr : You have to sanitize your dataset before use.
I think you're using Sea Ice Concentration CDR dataset from US National Centers for Environmental Information.
I downloaded seaice_conc_daily_sh_1980_v04r00.nc from there and got this result with your code.
Graphic is little bit different, but it's the same weird straight red line appeared on longitude ±90°.

Can you see red shoreline drawn on both plotted map?
Unfortunately, they're not from map image or separate shoreline data. They're included in your dataset as a predefined flag values, which intentionally positioned way outside the valid data range.
from USER GUIDE: NOAA/NSIDC Climate Data Record of Passive Microwave Sea Ice Concentration, Version 4,

Valid Range: 0 to 1. Note: Byte values are actually stored in the files from 0 to 100 but are presented by most, but not all, netCDF readers as values ranging from 0 to 1 because of a scaling factor attribute (scale_factor) for this variable of .01 that is applied by most netCDF readers. Flag values range from 251 to 255.




Flag Name
Value




Northern Hemisphere pole hole (the region around the pole not imaged by the sensor)
251


Lakes
252


Coast/Land adjacent to ocean
253


Land
254


Missing/Fill
255



After removing that "Non-data" from dataset with SIC[SIC > 1.0] = np.nan, new map would look like this.

And please don't forget to provide the dataset you've used if available, or at least redacted minimal one which can be used to reproduce your problem.
